# What's the correct way for proving by Well Ordering Principle that any positive integer can be expressed as a sum of powers of two?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following proof.

Proof:

Let $C = \{ m \:| \:\forall\: k \in \mathbb{Z}^+, k < 2^{m + 1}, k \neq 2^{a_1} + 2^{a_2} + \ldots + 2^{a_i}, a_i < m + 1 \}$, now, let's assume that this is a nonempty set, assuming this we are saying that there is a minimum element in the set (because of the Well Ordering Principle), let this element be $m_0$, this means that for every positive integer less than $2^{m_0 + 1}$ such integer can't be expressed as a sum of powers of 2, it follows that the statement holds for $m_0 - 1$, but this is a contradiction, because if it's true then there are integers less than $2^{m_0 + 1}$ that can be expressed as a sum of powers of two, then such a set has no minimum element, meaning it's empty.

QED

Is this proof the correct way of proving such property? Is convinging enough? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If your set is empty, that means that there is no $m$ that satisfies the given condition. But what that means is that given any $m$, it is false that every integer less than $2^{m+1}$ cannot be written as a sum of powers of two; which means that given any $m$, there is at least one integer $k\lt 2^{m+1}$ which *can* be written as a sum of powers of two. However, that is far less than what you are trying to prove, which is that *every* integer an be written as a sum of powers of two. All you did is prove that there is one that can be so written.

Comment: (Also, your argument does not work if the minimum happens to be $m_0=0$, because then $m_0-1$ is nonsense; or $m_0=1$ if your natural numbers start with $1$. So your argument is not correct, and even if it were it does not prove what you want it to prove)

Comment: "this means that for every positive integer less than 2m0+1 such integer can't be expressed as a sum of powers of 2"  Why would it mean that?  Wouldn't it only mean that there is at least one element between $2^{m_0} \le x < 2^{m_0+1}$ that isn't expressible.  It certainly wouldn't be *all* are inexpressible.  After all, we know all $k < 2^{m_0}$ are expressible.  Instead of doing the least power you should do the least integer itself.

Comment: Consider if $k$ is inexpressible then $k - 2^w$ is expressible if $2^w < k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct, and even if were it does not prove what you want it to prove.

The error in the argument itself is that you do not consider the possibility that $m_0$ is the least natural number, which would prevent you from considering $m_0-1$. You need to do that case.

And the reason your argument does not prove what you want it to prove, even if it were correct, is that the fact that set $C$ is empty does not establish what you want.

(You should really also have a quantifier for $i$, and your last inequality should be a $j$, not an $i$; that is, your condition has free variables, which makes it not quite right).

Namely: assume you have shown your set is empty. That means that given $m$, $m\notin C$. Which means that the given condition is false. That is,
$$\neg\left(\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}^+, k\lt 2^{m+1}\implies\forall j\geq 0(\forall a_1,\ldots,a_j\in\mathbb{N}( k\neq 2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+\cdots+2^{a_j})\right)$$
But the negation means that there exists $k$, $k\lt 2^{m+1}$, such that there is a $j\geq 0$ and nonnegative integers $a_1,\ldots,a_j$ such that $k=2^{a_1}+\cdots+w^{a_j}$.

So you are just proving that given any $m$, there is *at least one* integer $k$, less than $2^{m+1}$, which can be written as a sum of powers of $2$.

Yet you are trying to prove that *all* integers less than $2^{m+1}$ can be written as a sum of powers of $2$, not just that there is at least one that works.

So your set should really have the condition
$$\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}^+\left( k\lt 2^{m+1}\wedge \forall j\geq 0(\forall a_1,\ldots,a_k\in\mathbb{M}\ (k\neq 2^{a_1}+\cdots+2^{a_j})\right).$$
That is, the least element of $C$ is the smallest $m_0$ for which there is a counterexample less than $2^{m_0+1}$; so if $m_0$ is not equal to $0$, then there is no counterexample less than $2^{m_0}$, but there is one between $2^{m_0}$ and $2^{m_0+1}$.

Of course, with this condition your argument does not work, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of "for all" and "there exists" statements.  Here's a proof that you might be looking for:

Proof: Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers not expressible as a sum of powers of $2$.  For the sake of contradiction, assume $S$ is nonempty.  By the Well-Order Principle, $S$ has a least element, say $m \in S$.  Clearly, $m\neq1$ since $1=2^0$, so $m>2^0$.  Let $n$ be the largest natural number such that $m>2^n$.  Then $m-2^n>0$ and $m-2^n<m$.  So by our choice of $m$, $m-2^n \notin S$.  Therefore, $m-2^n=2^{n_1}+2^{n_2}+\ldots +2^{n_k}$ for some $n_i$.  However, then we have $m=2^n+2^{n_1}+2^{n_2}+\ldots +2^{n_k}$, contradicting our assumption. QED